# How to solve extra alignment tab has been changed to /cr

Tags: errors, europecv

I wanna make a CV in LaTeX template(`europecv`), but I have some problems with that.
I change other skills and competatance to other skills and certificate, but when I enter the certificates in there as:

```
\documentclass[helvetica,openbib,logo,notitle,flagCMYK,totpages]{europecv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.27cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}


\ecvname{Blah, Blah}
\ecvfootername{Blah Blah}
\ecvaddress{ a street, M alley, USA}
\ecvtelephone{041-1234567}
%\ecvfax{12345678}
\ecvemail{\url{Blah.Blah@gmail.com}}
\ecvnationality{American}
\ecvdateofbirth{apr 11 1998}
\ecvgender{Female}
%\ecvpicture[width=2cm]{lion.png}
\ecvfootnote{For more information call me please}



\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Other skills and certificate}{Risk Management Course Certified by: Tehran University, registered by IIIE, Nov 2007 ;\\
    Quality Management System Internal Audit based on ISO 9001:2000 QMS, ISO19011:2002-certified by: TUV ACADEMY RHEINLAND, May 2008 ;\\&
    Fundamental Concepts & Criterion Parts of EFQM Excellent Model, Certified by: KQR/ISC Jun 2010 ;\\&
    PRIMAVERA PROJECT PLANER: Certified BY: Technical and Vocational Training Organization, Feb 2010 ;\\&
    Internal Audit of Integrated Management System (IMS) Based on ISO 9001:2008 & ISO 14001:2004 & OHSAS 18001:2007, Certified by: TUV NORD, Oct 2012.}
```

I received this error:

> `extra alignment tab has been changed to /cr.`

How can I solve it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Probably you have too many columns. Does ecvitem expect 6? According to documentation it expects exactly none.

Answer (score 2):

You have several errors in your code.  Please see the corrected code:

```
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Other skills and certificate}%
  {Risk Management Course Certified by: Tehran University, registered by IIIE, Nov 2007; %\\ <======
  Quality Management System Internal Audit based on ISO 9001:2000 QMS,
  ISO19011:2002-certified by: TUV ACADEMY RHEINLAND, May 2008; %\\& <==============================
  Fundamental Concepts \& Criterion Parts of EFQM Excellent Model, % <======================
  Certified by: KQR/ISC Jun 2010; %\\& <==============================================
  PRIMAVERA PROJECT PLANER: Certified BY: Technical and Vocational 
  Training Organization, Feb 2010; %\\& <=============================================
  Internal Audit of Integrated Management System (IMS) Based on 
  ISO 9001:2008 \& ISO 14001:2004 \& OHSAS 18001:2007, Certified by: TUV NORD, Oct 2012.}
```

In the used class `\\&` is not allowed in command `\ecvitem`. I commented them out or masked `&` with `\&` to get it printed.

With this changes your code compiles with the following MWE

```
\documentclass[helvetica,openbib,totpages]{europecv}% europecv2013 europecv
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.27cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{url}

\ecvname{Surname, Name}
\ecvfootername{Name Surname}
\ecvaddress{House number, street name, postcode, city, country}
\ecvtelephone[(Remove if not relevant)]{(Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvfax{(Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvemail{\url{email@address.com} (Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvnationality{(Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvdateofbirth{(Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvgender{(Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvpicture[width=2cm]{example-image}
\ecvfootnote{} % 


\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}

\begin{europecv}
\ecvpersonalinfo[5pt]
\ecvitem{\large\textbf{Desired employment/ Occupational~field}}{\large\textbf{(Remove if not relevant)}}

\ecvsection{Work experience}
\ecvitem{Dates}{Add separate entries for each relevant post occupied, starting from the most recent. (Remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem{Occupation or position held}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Main activities and responsibilities}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Name and address of employer}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Type of business or sector}{\ldots}

\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Other skills and certificate}%
  {Risk Management Course Certified by: Tehran University, registered by IIIE, Nov 2007; %\\ <======
  Quality Management System Internal Audit based on ISO 9001:2000 QMS,
  ISO19011:2002-certified by: TUV ACADEMY RHEINLAND, May 2008; %\\& <==============================
  Fundamental Concepts \& Criterion Parts of EFQM Excellent Model, % <======================
  Certified by: KQR/ISC Jun 2010; %\\& <==============================================
  PRIMAVERA PROJECT PLANER: Certified BY: Technical and Vocational 
  Training Organization, Feb 2010; %\\& <=============================================
  Internal Audit of Integrated Management System (IMS) Based on 
  ISO 9001:2008 \& ISO 14001:2004 \& OHSAS 18001:2007, Certified by: TUV NORD, Oct 2012.}
\end{europecv}

\end{document}
```

to the resulting page:

[image: resulting page]